# How to fix text alignment issues in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with a few text alignment problems, here are two images:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Notice:

1. TRUE and FALSE are centered (probably because they are keywords.
2. **Some** hebrew/arabic words are aligned on the left, some on the right (about half and half).
3. Some of my non-rtl language text is aligned on the right.

I always paste in with COMMAND+SHIFT+V to remove all formatting, and I've tried to clear all formatting, but it doesn't fix the issue.

I would like:

- For true and false to be aligned left without caps.
- For all non-rtl words to be aligned left.
- For all rtl words (Hebrew and Arabic) to be aligned right (and written right to left).

How do I fix these issues?

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as [**plain text table**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/)(NOT as IMAGE) to the question. Adding such "markdown tables" greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.